# Rails API Forgot Password not Rendering View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-recoverable

so i'm building a forgot password in my Rails API, i was able to send the reset password email, but when i go to the link, it gives me `204 No Content`.
I'm using lvh.me to test my api subdomain in development

This is my passwords_controller.rb

```
class User::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def create
    puts params
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      render json: {status: 'ok'}, status: :ok, location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    else
      render json: {error: ['Error occurred']}, status: :internal_server_error
    end
  end

  # GET /user/password/edit?reset_password_token=blablabla
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    set_minimum_password_length
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end

  # PUT /user/password
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.empty?
      resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
      if Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password
        flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
        set_flash_message!(:notice, flash_message)
        resource.after_database_authentication
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message!(:notice, :updated_not_active)
      end
      respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
    else
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end


  protected
    def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
      Devise.sign_in_after_reset_password ? after_sign_in_path_for(resource) : new_session_path(resource_name)
    end

    # The path used after sending reset password instructions
    def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
      new_session_path(resource_name) if is_navigational_format?
      puts new_session_path(resource_name) if is_navigational_format?
    end

    # Check if a reset_password_token is provided in the request
    def assert_reset_token_passed
      if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
        set_flash_message(:alert, :no_token)
        redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
      end
    end

    # Check if proper Lockable module methods are present & unlock strategy
    # allows to unlock resource on password reset
    def unlockable?(resource)
      resource.respond_to?(:unlock_access!) &&
        resource.respond_to?(:unlock_strategy_enabled?) &&
        resource.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email)
    end

    def translation_scope
      'devise.passwords'
    end
end
```

The generated link looks like this: `http://api.lvh.me:3000/user/password/edit?reset_password_token=blablabla`

My controllers and views structure is:

```
controllers/user/passwords_controller.rb
views/user/passwords/edit.html.erb
```

My routes.rb for user looks like this:

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'user' do
      devise_for  :users,
                  path: '/user',
                  path_names: {
                    registration: 'signup',
                    sign_in: 'login',
                    sign_out: 'logout'
                  },
                  controllers: {
                    sessions: 'user/sessions',
                    registrations: 'user/registrations',
                    passwords: 'user/passwords'
                  }
         end
end
```

[image: Response to user/passsword/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that i had

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::API` which was keeping me from rendering Views, simply changing to

`class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` resolved the issue